# how can i bind custom remote data that change in success handler to Grid fields

Tags: javascript, jsgrid

I am using [jsGrid](http://js-grid.com) in my project and i have problem with edit data from ajax to bind in JsGrid fields.

how can i bind that edited data to Grid fields in JsGrid
for example:

```
loadData: function (item) {
                return $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "url.html?cmd=fill",
                    data: null,
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                          var list=eval(data);
                           //this loop is for example
                           for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
                            { 
                               list[i].id=i+1;
                                //how to bind this list to Grid Fields
                            }
                    }
                });
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return a promise resolved with the data after processing:

```
loadData: function (item) {
    var d = $.Deferred();    

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url.html?cmd=fill",
        data: null,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var list=eval(data);
            for(var i=0;i<list.length;i++)
            {
                list[i].id=i+1;
            }
            d.resolve(list);
        }
    });

    return d.promise();
}
```